# VBA Find&Replace cell content based on a lookup table using offset

Tags: excel, vba

Scratching my head over this simple issue: I have a sub to find and replace a value in my `Sheet.Sheet1` column `F` based on a table in `Sheet.Classification` column `B`. The value is replaced by the content of `Classification Column F`, hence the `Offset(0, 4)`.

The sub works fine excepts that I want it to replace the entire content of my cell in column `F` in `Sheet 1` (rather than just the `Lookup.Value` found).

```
Sub ABC()


Dim rngData     As Range
Dim rngLookup   As Range
Dim Lookup      As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set rngData = .Range("F2", .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

With Sheets("Classification")
 Set rngLookup = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each Lookup In rngLookup
If Lookup.Value = "" Then
    rngData.Replace what:=Lookup.Value, _
                    Replacement:=Lookup.Offset(0, 4).Value, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False
End If
Next Lookup
End Sub
```

Any help?

Comment: So rngData.replace means you want to replace the data in the same row as lookup? It's a bit unclear. Maybe you can add an example?

Comment: Yes that's right. Let's say in Sheet1, F2 I have "First Prize is for the winner" and in the sheetClassification, B2 I have "First Prize" I want my macro to grab the content of C2 (still from Classification) and insert it in B2 (of Sheet1). Hence, if there is a match between my two sheets, I the cell content of my original sheet to be replaced by my offset value. Is this more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify the IF statement:

```
If Lookup.Value = "" Then
    rngData.Value =Lookup.Offset(0, 4).Value
End If
```

Using the .Replace method is like the REPLACE() function, it will swap out parts of a string and not the whole contents.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace

Comment: I have tried this and it now replaces all cell content but not with teh right value. Any idea why?